# Добавление данных на страницу без перезагрузки в реальном времени

Tags: веб-программирование, php

Здравствуйте, мастера web разработки!)

Прошу оставить свои мнения и советы ниже

Есть сайт

http://selims.ru/arenda/Samara/

Там реализована динамическая таблица в которую добавляются поля автоматический из БД

Тоесть нет необходимости обновлять страницу. Можно отслеживать всю инфу в реальном времени

Какие средствами это можно сделать?
Возможное есть какие-то готовые решения?
Буду благодарен за ссылки на справочную информацию

Спасибо!)

Comment: Делаете аякс запрос на сервер, в момент пока происходит запрос устанавливаете анимацию загрузки. На сервере формируете ответ в виде   JSON или XML, разницы нет, и отдаете его обратно. Клиент принимает данные, убирает анимацию загрузки и обрабатывает полученные данные как ему захочется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подгружайте данные при помощи AJAX. Используйте jQuery